# How to access values in an xmm register

Tags: assembly, nasm, cpu-registers, sse

I'm looking to sum a total of integers inputted by the user. I have a loop set up by using compares and jumps. Here is the way I'm approaching it, but I can't get it to work.

```
;====Display message asking user========
mov         qword rdi, stringformat                                 
mov         qword rsi, promptfloatnumber                                      
mov         qword rax, 0                                            
call        printf            

;====Input number========
push        qword 0                                                
mov         qword  rdi, floatinputformat                            
mov         qword  rsi, rsp                                         
mov         qword  rax, 0                                           
call        scanf                                            

pop         r14

;===== Copy input to SSE======
push        r14                                              
movsd       xmm1, [rsp]                                      
pop         rax

;=== Keeps a total count throughout the loops? =====                                      
addsd       xmm0,xmm1        ;xmm0 = xmm0 + xmm1

;Then it jumps back up if user wants to input more values
```

Then I just need to display xmm0 which is the total right? I'm not sure how to. I tried something like this.

```
mov         rdi, formatfloatdecimaloutput              
mov qword   rax, 1                                           
call        printf
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how `clang` on my OS X machine does it -- annotated for clarity:

```
# this is the constant '(double)2.5'
LCPI0_0:
    .quad   4612811918334230528     ## double 2.500000e+00
                                    ##  (0x4004000000000000)

    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi      # arg1 = format string address
    movsd   LCPI0_0(%rip), %xmm0    # float arg2 = 2.5
    movb    $1, %al                 # number of floating-point arguments
    callq   _printf


    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:
    .asciz   "%f\n" # here's the format string
```